# C# Console Application - Query IEnumerable and reformat Date

Tags: c#, linq, console-application, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable I query to get some data--and included in that query is a field, EndDate. However, I'd like to change that format of the End Date. Is there a way to do this in the query, or do I need to query then change the date? Sample code below.

Currently, sc.EndDate is formatted as "mm/dd/yyyy" (ex., 05/28/2019) but I need to get that field as "dd-MMM-yyyy" (ex., 28-May-2019).

Any thoughts or ideas?

EDIT: my class "Score" gets everything as STRING, as I'm getting it from a CSV file earlier in my code. class below:

```
        public class Score
    {
        [CsvColumn(Name = "Name", FieldIndex = 1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "StudentId", FieldIndex = 2)]
        public string StudentId { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "Email", FieldIndex = 3)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "LastLogin", FieldIndex = 4)]
        public string LastLogin { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "PlacementAssessmentNumber", FieldIndex = 5)]
        public string PlacementAssessmentNumber { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "TotalNumberofPlacements Taken", FieldIndex = 6)]
        public string TotalNumPlacements { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "StartDate", FieldIndex = 7)]
        public string StartDate { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "StartTime", FieldIndex = 8)]
        public string StartTime { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "EndDate", FieldIndex = 9)]
        public string EndDate { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "EndTime", FieldIndex = 10)]
        public string EndTime { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "ProctoredAssessment", FieldIndex = 11)]
        public string ProctoredAssessment { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "TimeinPlacement", FieldIndex = 12)]
        public string TimeInPlacement { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "PlacementResults", FieldIndex = 13)]
        public string PlacementResults { get; set; }

        IEnumerable<Score> scores = cc.Read<Score>(resultsPath, inputFileDescription);

        string whereSort = "Yes/Complete";

        var scoresById =
            from sc in scores
            orderby sc.Name
            where ((sc.ProctoredAssessment.ToString() == whereSort.ToString()))
            select new { sc.StudentId, sc.PlacementResults, sc.ProctoredAssessment, sc.EndDate };
```

Comment: What type is `EndDate`? `string` or `DateTime`?

Comment: What do you mean by "is formatted as"? In what context?

Comment: Date formatting should be part of the presentation layer not the data layer. I assume the date fields are stored as dates.

Comment: @Sweeper Whoops, forgot to add that! It's coming as a String, all of them are--editing the post to show my class Score now.

Comment: @PeterSmith Sorry--forgot to add my class definitions. I've updated the post with the class definitions. I'm getting all this data from a CSV, and all the fields are Strings in my class.

Comment: Can you change the `EndDate`'s type to `DateTime`? I know you are reading it from CSV, but if you change the attribute to `[CsvColumn(Name = "EndDate", FieldIndex = 9, FormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]`, the [library that you are using](https://humanprinter.github.io/enkoni/html/6c2a1e58-02d0-fef5-55db-4cd86ec0d37a.htm) _might_ be able to read parse the string.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm using the LINQtoCSV library. I'm having trouble finding any documentation on changing that date format. In my class I can (and now have) changed that datatype to DateTime, however, I can't format it properly.

Comment: @LoganSBishop You can do `EndDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyy")`

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, Sweeper! That worked like a charm! So simple! I guess I was really overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sweeper, I've found a solution. In my class, I've changed the String EndDate to DateTime EndDate and I've casted the field ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"). Guess I was really over thinking it!